# What are the necessary conditions to prevent latch-up problem for Oscillators?

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, oscillator, latch, negative-feedback

In his chapter on oscillator design, Razavi discusses the issue of latch-up and proposes several methods to eliminate it. However, he doesn't provide explanations for these methods. Could anyone provide insights into the following three questions?

1:Why does providing negative feedback near zero frequency in Figure 15.6 eliminate the problem of latch-up?

2:Why must the total number of inversions in the loop of ring oscillators be odd to prevent latch-up?

3:Is there a common principle underlying both the first and second methods?

Fig 15.6
[image: 15.6]
Fig 15.15
[image: 15.15]